# Source for Authentic Mantras?

Tags: vedas, mantras, book-recommendation

Are there any **Sources (Books/Websites/Apps)** with **Authentic Mantras**, Original form of Mantras, Meaning of Mantras and how to pronounce/practice it.

These days, **there are Mantras for everything**; so many online gurus popping up and giving Mantras by **randomly mixing various Sanskrit words**.
So I got little skeptical and started to **believe in Mantras from Vedas only**.

Should I trust all Mantras or old Mantras written in Vedas only?

Comment: What type of mantras are you looking for?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I just want trustful source, Any Book of Mantra, or Website with list of mantras.

Comment: This looks a broad question though, you may look at [Collection of Commonly recited Shlokas with Meanings](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_general/allshlokawmean.html?lang=sa)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the following statement of the OP, I am providing answer.

> So I got little skeptic and started to believe in Mantras from Vedas
>   only.

If you are looking for Video of recitation of mantras from Rig Veda, the following is the link for hearing them.

http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/rigveda/shakala-samhita/mandal-01/

1. You can select Mandala first, so that the site will take you to appropriate Mandala.
2. Then you can select the Hymn number within the Mandala.

---

In respect of other Vedas, click on SAMHITAS button, on the top , which will navigate to appropriate Veda.